# How to calculate purity?

Tags: clustering

In cluster analysis how do we calculate purity? What's the equation?

I'm not looking for a code to do it for me.

[image]

Let $\omega_k$ be cluster k, and $c_j$ be class j.

So is purity practically accuracy? it looks like were summing the amount of truly classified class per cluster over the sample size.

[equation source](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html)

The question is what is the relationship between the output and the input?

If there's Truly Positive(TP), Truly Negative (TN), Falsely Positive(FP), Falsely Negative (FN).
Is it $Purity = \frac{TP_K}{(TP+TN+FP+FN)}$?

Comment: If you just need a quick definition: The top google search on *clustering purity* \*\* links [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html) which gives a mathematical definition. (\*\* for me, at least -- your individual results may differ)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'purity', but David Colquhoun uses "the black magical assay of purity of heart" as an example of binomial sampling on pp. 111-114 of his excellent textbook Lectures on Biostatistics (1971) which is available as a free pdf from the author's website: http://www.dcscience.net Even if it is irrelevant to your question, it's a great story.

Comment: In classification trees some of the functions to measure impurity are: resubstitution error, gini-index and entropy. (Classification trees perform a specific form of clustering, so I think this should be relevant.) Hope this helps!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Within the context of cluster analysis, [Purity is an external evaluation criterion of cluster quality.](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html#fig:clustfg3)  It is the percent of the total number of objects(data points) that were classified correctly, in the unit range [0..1].

$$Purity = \frac 1 N \sum_{i=1}^k max_j | c_i \cap t_j | $$

where $N$ = number of objects(data points), $k$ = number of clusters, $c_i$ is a cluster in $C$, and $t_j$ is the classification which has the max count for cluster $c_i$

When we say "correctly" that implies that each cluster $c_i$ has identified a group of objects as the same class that the ground truth has indicated.  We use the ground truth classification $t_i$ of those objects as the measure of assignment correctness, however to do so we must know which cluster $c_i$ maps to which ground truth classification $t_i$.  If it were 100% accurate then each $c_i$ would map to exactly 1 $t_i$, but in reality our $c_i$ contains some points whose ground truth classified them as several other classifications.  Naturally then we can see that the highest clustering quality will be obtained by using the $c_i$ to $t_i$ mapping which has the most number of correct classifications i.e. $c_i \cap t_i$.  That is where the the $max$ comes from in the equation.

To calculate Purity first create your [confusion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)  This can be done by looping through each cluster $c_i$ and counting how many objects were classified as each class $t_i$.

```
   |  T1 |  T2  |  T3
---------------------
C1 |  0  |  53  |  10
C2 |  0  |  1   |  60
C3 |  0  |  16  |  0
```

Then for each cluster $c_i$, select the maximum value from its row, sum them together and finally divide by the total number of data points.

```
Purity = (53 + 60 + 16) / 140 = 0.92142
```

Comment: can you also please answer for entropy?

Comment: here my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709562/how-to-calculate-clustering-entropy-a-working-example-or-software-code/35716423

Comment: I think you "overflow the logic" when say "$t_j$ is the classification ... max counts". There is no need for $max_{j}$ then. By the way, high purity does not shows the correctness of classification, does it?